# Magento 2 - Stock Qty at the time of the order

Tags: magento2

I need to get the stock quantity of each product (at the time of the order) to show a custom message on the customer order page view.

Any help? It seems that the products stock information is not stored.

Many Thanks

Comment: customer order page view means?

Comment: The page in the customer account where the selected order details are shown.

Answer (score 0):

Use below code your able to find product available stock

```
$product_Id = '123';
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$stockInfo = $objectManager->get('Magento\CatalogInventory\Api\StockRegistryInterface')->getStockItem($product_Id);
$stockqty = (int)$stockInfo->getQty();
echo $stockqty;
```

Comment: I need the stock qty of the product when the order was placed, not now.

Comment: @Shorabh Don't use object manager. Inject the class and use it. This is not a good practice.

Answer (score 0):

Create event for the `sales_order_place_after` and in that observer and write the below code in that observer file.

```
$order = $observer->getEvent()->getOrder(); 
$items = $order->getAllVisibleItems();
foreach($items as $item) {
   $productId = $item->getProductId();
// here you can use @shorabh kumar logic to get the stock details
}
```